# How to do multi post in Python?

Tags: python, post

I want my python post faster , and make it multithreading

```html
# Data SET
env = "PROD"
accNameLocked = env
accountPassword = "ddd"
appIdKey = "3b356c1bac5ad9735ad62f24d43414eb59715cc4d21b178835626ce0d2daa77d"
fdcBrowserData = ""
language = "US-EN"
openiForgotInNewWindow = "true"
path = "/"
requestUri = "/login.html"
rv = "1"
scnt = "31b0020ec593370dc388f8965e"
view = "5"
Mode_File = "r+"
open_file = open(appleId,Mode_File)
read_me = open_file.readlines()
for i in read_me:
    i.strip()
    get_data = {tPassword,"appIdKey":appIdKey,"appleId":i,"fdcBrowserData":fdcBrndowuestUri":requestUri,"rv":rv,"scnt":scnt,"view":view}
    connect = p.post(url,params=get_data).content
    valid_msg = "YAY"
    dia_msg = "Hey"
    if (valid_msg in connect):
 print("Valid :>> "+i)
 save_valid = open("rzlt/live.txt","a+")
 save_valid.write("\n"+i)
    elif(dia_msg in connect):
 print("Die :>> "+i)
 save_invalid = open("rzlt/die.txt","a+")
 save_invalid.write("\n"+i)
```

how to make it multiposting?, thanks alot so it gonna post the url faster, because the normal run is only one by one

Comment: Do you know if the server has some kind of rate-limitting? Because if it does, then concurrent requests may not help you there because the server will just block the new connections.

Answer (score 0):

Well, here are several suggestions to fix some issues with your code:

- you are never closing the files that you open; you should always close them explicitly (or use `with open() as f:`, which closes them automatically).
- `i.strip()` returns a new string, but you are not using it; you need to assign the return value to a variable, probably `i = i.strip()`.
- you can use `for line in f:` to iterate over the lines in the opened file one by one instead of using `f.readlines()`; my suggestion reads from the file as the content is needed, it does not read all at once into memory.
- your variable called `get_data` is not a valid `dict`.

Also, you do not show your imports, so I don't know what lib you use to make the HTTP requests, and you also never defined some variables that you used.

Nevertheless here is a slightly improved version of your code:

```
with open('your-filename.txt', "r+") as f,\
        open("rzlt/live.txt", "a+") as f_valid,\
        open("rzlt/die.txt", "a+") as f_invalid:

    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if len(line) > 0:       # avoid empty lines
            data = {
                "appleId": line,
                "appIdKey": appIdKey,
                "fdcBrowserData": fdcBrowserData,
                "requestUri": requestUri,
                "rv": rv,
                "scnt": scnt,
                "view": view,
            }
            response_content = p.post(url, params=data).content

            if "YAY" in response_content:
                print("Valid :>> ", line)
                f_valid.write("{}\n".format(line))
            elif "Hey" in response_content:
                print("Invalid :>> ", line)
                f_invalid.write("{}\n".format(line))
```

Comment: i want my script execute `response_content = p.post(url,params=get_data).content` multiple so it faster showing the result

Comment: @CahyaDarmaWijaya have you looked into the documentation of Pythons `threading` and `multiprocessing` modules?

Comment: `import requests as p`, i had looked the threading and multiprocessing getting confuse where i have to place it